# Chrome extension warning: 'input' is not allowed for specified platform

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to read focused text input when hotkey pressed and commit text after replacing some characters. Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "EasyFa",
"description": "This extension easily convert mistyped English sentences with keyboard in English mode or vice versa.",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
    "48": "48.png"
},

"background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"commands": {
    "convert-text": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+0",
            "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+0"
        },
        "description": "Convert text"
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "input"
]}
```

And here is the warning message:

*There were warnings when trying to install this extension:

'input' is not allowed for specified platform.*

I searched the warning message but didn't find even one related topic on the net!
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not use Chrome OS.

> "Use the chrome.input.ime API to implement a custom IME for Chrome
>   OS."
>   from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime

All you need is set "tabs" in "permissions" and delete "input".